# Circular Motion Under Gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, stability

This question has been asked in a roundabout way before, but I have not got the exact answer I am looking for.

I have an object, say a ball, attached to a string which has its other end fixed in place. Then I apply a force to the ball sufficiently large enough to cause the ball to rotate around the fixed end in such a way that it forms a circular path. The plane in which the ball travels is vertical and perpendicular to the ground, so the weight of the ball will affect the centripetal force at any given point.

As the angle the ball has rotated through increases, the velocity of the ball decreases because the kinetic energy of the ball is transferred into gravitational potential energy.

Now suppose the ball is given just the right initial speed so that when it reaches the exact top of the circle after starting from the lowest point (the equilibrium position), the ball will have a velocity of exactly $0 m/s$.

This is very much a theoretical scenario, however, my question is: Which way will the ball go? Will the ball come down the same way it went up, or will the ball continue to form a full circular path?

Comment: If it is attached to a string your scenario will not work. The ball will leave the circular orbit before it reaches the top, because the string will not keep its tension unless the centripetal force exceeds the parallel component of the weight. If ball is attached to a rod then your question makes sense (and the answer is, that it will take the ball infinite time to reach the top – this is, by the way, an initial condition for which the mathematical pendulum can be solved exactly).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the scenario, I think the ball would simply fall straight down, assuming the string is not rigid.
However, it would not necessarily be able to travel on a circular path in the first place since even before it reaches 0 m/s, its velocity might not be large enough to pull the string enough to straighten it.

As I'm getting downvoted.. If the string is supposed to be rigid, the ball would simple stay at the top if it really has no velocity in either horizontal direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the rope is rigid, the ball will stay on the top, being in a state we call 'unstable equilibrium'. In this state, the ball does not 'want' to go anywhere, but is very willing to do so if somebody gives it the faintest push. The opposite of this is the 'stable equilibrium', for example the ball at its lowest point. In this case, the ball stays near the equilibrium point even when someone pushes is, as long as the push is not too hard.

If the rope is not rigid, however, the centripedal force will, at some point, be exceeded by the gravitational force, and the ball will leave the circular orbit falling down.

Comment: "if somebody gives it the faintest push" That push will inevitably come, via transmitted vibrations from the floor, air currents, or even from fortuitous imbalances in bombardment of the ball by air molecules hitting it on opposite sides.

Comment: Indeed, and such scenario only exists in ideal situations...

Answer (score 0):

Energy is conserved and this means that if the ball starts at the North Pole with a small velocity it will accelerate due to gravity going from North Pole to South Pole and then decelerate from South Pole to North Pole returning at it with the same velocity and repeating the same cycle forever. The ball energy is in fact just greater that the energy at rest at the North Pole.